# Use of inline Nav in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am use Jqgrid.
In which i use inine nav for add new rows.
My Inline nav code

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav','#Pager',
{
 editParams : {
   extraparam : {
    extraParamId : function() {
            return allExtraId;
    }
   }
 }
});
```

So my Question is that when i am use inlineNav so this code navGrid is require or not

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager', {
 edit : false,
 add : false    
});
```

Please Reply....
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call of `navGrid` is really required before calling of `inlineNav`. The reason is that the pager creates per default only three parts: left, center and right. The parts as as `<td>` elements of the row of table in the pager. For example if you don't call `navGrid` you will have empty left part of the pager like below:

```html
<td align="left" id="pager_left"></td>
```

If you call `navGrid` for example in the form

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager",
    {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false});
```

the left part of the pager will be changed to

```html
<td align="left" id="pager_left">
    <table class="ui-pg-table navtable"
           style="float: left; table-layout: auto;"
           border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody><tr></tr></tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

The current implementation of `inlineNav` just uses [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) to add additional buttons to the navigator which must be created before. How you will see from [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L1993) of code the method `navButtonAdd` uses `$(".navtable", "#pager")` to find the navigator table inside of the pager. Only if the navigator will be found the method `navButtonAdd` add additional buttons inside of it.

So you really need first **create the navigator bar in the pager before you call `inlineNav`**.