# Want to create JQgrid with inline add,edit,save without any buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Below is my requirement:

1. Initially JQgrid should be Empty
2. On click of Jqgrid an new row has to be added with auto ID
3. On lost focus of row data should be saved to DB
4. On click of row user should be able to edit it and on lost focus data should be saved to DB

   ```
   var lastsel;
   jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
       url: "/TransactionType/GetGridData/",
       datatype: 'json',
       mtype: 'GET',
       height: "300",

       colNames: ['Customer ID', 'Contact Name', 'Address', 'City', 'Postal Code'],
       colModel: [
         { name: 'CustomerID', index: 'CustomerID', width: 100, align: 'left' },
         { name: 'ContactName', index: 'ContactName', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true },
         { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 300, align: 'left', editable: true },
         { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true },
         { name: 'PostalCode', index: 'PostalCode', width: 100, align: 'left', editable: true }
       ],

       pager: jQuery('#pager'),
       rowNum: 10,
       rowList: [1, 3, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
       recordpos: 'right',
       viewrecords: true,
       sortorder: "desc",
       sortname: "CustomerID",
       sorttype: "integer",
       multiselect: false,
       caption: "Manipulating JSON Data",
       emptyrecords: "No records found.",
       loadtext: "Loading...",
       loadonce: true,
       pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
       jsonReader: {
           repeatitems: true,
           cell: "cell"
       },

       onSelectRow: function (id) {
           if (id) {
               if (id !== lastsel) {
                   jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                   jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                   lastsel = id;
               } else {
                   jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                   lastsel = "";


                   debugger;
                   var rows = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getRowData');
                   var paras = new Array();
                   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                       var row = rows[i];
                       paras.push($.param(row));
                   }
                   var rids = $('#list').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                   var n = rids.length;
                   var nth_row_id = rids[n - 1];

                   jQuery("#list").addRow(n + 1, parameters = {
                       edit: true,
                       editicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
                       add: true,
                       addicon: "ui-icon-plus",
                       save: true,
                       saveicon: "ui-icon-disk",
                       cancel: true,
                       cancelicon: "ui-icon-cancel",
                       addParams: { useFormatter: false },
                       editParams: {}
                   });                     


               }
           }




       },
       editurl: "/TransactionType/GetTotalCount",


   });
   ```

This is my Jqgrid where i'm able to add the row but not with auto generated id and I'm not able to call the controller method after lost focus of row or Enter key.

Comment: What is your question? What problem during implementing of your requirements you want to ask here? stackoverflow is not the place where you just formulate your requirements and somebody implements all for you for free.

Comment: @oleg please refer my edited question.my problem is Not able to generate auto id and not able to save data...

Answer (score 2):

jqGrid includes [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) method which allows to add to the navigator bar (created by `navGrid` called typically with `add: false, edit: false` option, see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13264915/315935)) Add, Edit, Save and Cancel buttons. If the user click on one from the button the corresponding inline editing method will be called. One can use `editParams` and `addParams.addRowParams` to specify any additional options of inline editing methods (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19104829/315935) for example).

You current code use `addRow` directly. The second option (`parameters =`) contains wrong syntax. If you would need to generate unique id I would recommend you to use `$.jgrid.randId()` instead of usage `n + 1`. The first, and the only, parameter of `addRow` is object with options. If you use `adRow` directly you can use `rowID` option to specify the id of new added row. If no `rowID` option is specified jqGrid uses `$.jgrid.randId()` automatically to generate unique rowid of new row.

The ids of all inline editing buttons are set based on the id of the grid and a suffix: "_iladd", "_iledit", "_ilsave", "_ilcancel". For example is the grid have `id="list"` then the id of Save button will be `"list_ilsave"`. If required you can disable any button by addressing it by its id (for example `$("#list_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');` - enable Save button and `$("#list_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');` - disable it). In the same way you can use `jQuery.click` to simulate click on any button. For example `$("#list_ilsave").click();` will simulate clicking on the Save button.

If the user clicks on Add button the new row (`<tr>`) will get additional class `"jqgrid-new-row"`. You can use the fact to find rows added by `addRow`.

You can use `editoptions.dataEvents` to register `blur` or `focusout`. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257794/315935) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667051/315935) could provide some code fragmants which could help you.

It could be important to refresh the ids of the grid with the values generated in DB after successful saving. There are many ways to implement this. One of the most easy way would be to reload the grid after successful saving the row. See the code from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19104829/315935). Another way will be to return the new id from the web method specified by `editurl` ("/TransactionType/GetTotalCount" in your code). Using `aftersavefunc` callback you can get the response of `editurl` and makes modification of the id of in the grid. See relatively long code of `aftersavefunc` in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16002113/315935) as an example.

Comment: @Oleg..Excellent answer..thank you very much..i was looking for this..

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for your answer....Now I want to calculate cell1 and cell2 of Jqgrid and display in cell3...How can i achieve it on select of cell3? tried with onSelectCell but it's not firing as the cell is editable

Comment: @user3015994: You are welcome! [One](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10667051/315935) from the answers which I referenced do what you asked (see `recomputeAmount` function). I recommend you to read [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) of stackoverflow to understand the rules of it. The goal of stackoverflow is to share good questions and the corresponding answers *with other people*. Because of that one should not ask cumulative questions or ask new questions in comment. Such questions will be very difficult be found or not found at all during searching. So it will have no value for other.

Comment: @user3015994: Try to formulate your question simple, but clear for readers. For example you wrote "I want to calculate cell1 and cell2 of Jqgrid and display in cell3...How can i achieve it on select of cell3". It'a absolutely unclear what you mean. Do you mean *loading of data* in columns cell1 and cell2 and displaying some function from cell1 and cell2 in the column cell3? Do you mean that column cell3 in not editable and you want set cell3 *after* saving the row? Do you have cell3 editable, but you want adjust cell3 contain on changing focus? ... I can continue to guess...